# Zeppelin disconnected

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I downloaded zeppelin binary package and started it. However it's disconnected.
Here is the log:

```
 INFO [2016-01-12 14:37:56,592] ({main} QuartzScheduler.java[initialize]:305) - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.2.1) 'Defau
ltQuartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

 INFO [2016-01-12 14:37:56,593] ({main} StdSchedulerFactory.java[instantiate]:1339) - Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initi
alized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
 INFO [2016-01-12 14:37:56,593] ({main} StdSchedulerFactory.java[instantiate]:1343) - Quartz scheduler version: 2.2.1
 INFO [2016-01-12 14:37:56,593] ({main} QuartzScheduler.java[start]:575) - Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
 INFO [2016-01-12 14:37:56,805] ({main} ServerImpl.java[initDestination]:94) - Setting the server's publish address to be /
 INFO [2016-01-12 14:37:56,888] ({main} WebInfConfiguration.java[unpack]:478) - Extract jar:file:/data/users/huser/zeppelin/zeppelin-
web-0.5.5-incubating.war!/ to /tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-zeppelin-web-0.5.5-incubating.war-_-any-/webapp
 INFO [2016-01-12 14:37:57,040] ({main} StandardDescriptorProcessor.java[visitServlet]:284) - NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.
apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
 INFO [2016-01-12 14:37:57,941] ({main} AbstractConnector.java[doStart]:338) - Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
 INFO [2016-01-12 14:37:57,941] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[main]:108) - Started zeppelin server
```

I searched and found that port+1 is the websocket port. However, it's not listening:

## netstat -na | grep 8080

tcp        0      0 :::8080                     :::*                        LISTEN

## netstat -na | grep 8081

noting...

And the web return the error:

**WebSocket connection to 'ws://ip:8080/ws' failed: Establishing a tunnel via proxy server failed.**

Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Comment: The http port and websocket port is the same port. How does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure port forwarding command executes on yr client system all the time you use zeppelin

ssh  -i ~/keys/mykey.pem -N -L 8122:xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8890 hadoop@yy.yyy.yyy.yyy